# jQuery/javascript and setInterval not working correctly within mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so basically I'm implementing a simple horizontal scroller. The function gets fired when I move the mouse into the correct div but only once and doesn't keep looping after the interval time. Any help appreciated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toparrow').mouseenter(function(e) {
        var func = scrollroller(1);
        setInterval(func,1);
    }).mouseleave(function() {

    });

    function scrollroller(velocity) {
        $('#roller').animate({left:'+='+velocity},1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var func = function(){ scrollroller(1); };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
var func = scrollroller(1);
```

This isn't assigning the `scrollroller` function to `func`, it is invoking `scrollroller()` with a parameter of '1' and storing the result in `func`.  You probably want to do something like:

```
setInterval("scrollroller(1);",1);  //alternately:  setInterval(scrollroller,1,1);
```

Note that the alternate syntax may have [issues in IE](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/407).